# pyodbc - cannot connect to DSN

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to my database, but I can't establish connection. Here is my python code:

```
def connectToDB():
    connection = None

    while connection is None:
        try:
            connection = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=FootNet;UID=root;PWD=password')
        except:
            print("\n[DB connector]  Error connecting to database. Trying again in 1 sec.")

        time.sleep(1)
    return connection
```

I set up DSN as follows:

[image: ODBC Data Source Administrator]

When I click test, the connection is successful. But I cannot connect in python. Any clues what could be a problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

#### edit:

I receive the following error:

> `pyodbc.Error: ('IM014', '[IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')`

Comment: any error message in Python?

Comment: Not with this kind of code, but how to print out error? I just guess that now try block isn't successful, so it prints out my message.

Comment: remove try-except block just for now

Comment: pyodbc.Error: ('IM014', '[IM014] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Comment: Suggestion: In the future, instead of just a generic "Error connecting to database." message, consider including at least some of the actual error message to give an indication of what the specific problem is. Of course, for troubleshooting purposes a full stack trace is best.

Comment: It sounds like you have installed the 64-bit version of the ODBC driver and are trying to use it from 32-bit Python (or vice versa).

Comment: Now I changed to 32-bit driver and it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the error message, the problem probably lies in the architecture mismatch between the driver and application (pyodbc) you're using.

So make sure that the driver and app are both using 32-bit / 64-bit version.